# PostgreSQL update column from another column in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

table called labor. i have a column called code which has hundreds of code but the codes only start with a 1, 2 or 4. I am trying to update a new column in the same table that contains the first digit in each code.

```
 existing column  column to update(exists but is empty)
 code             type_
 113249            1
 135435            1   
 254646            2
 208984            2
 409098            4
 429540            4
```

the code column is numeric and the type_ column is numeric as well

here is what I have tried but it has not worked

```
update labor set type_ = case code
            when code::text like '%1' then 1 
            when code::text like '%2' then 2
            when code::text like '%4' then 4
            end
```

Comment: `LIKE '1%'... LIKE '2%', etc...` The wildcard is in the wrong place. But.. @RomanTkzchuk's answer below is a better approach anyway.

Comment: @JNevill Roman gave me the correct answer but how do I answer it the way I was trying?

Comment: Like I said above, put your wildcard behind the number, not in front.

Comment: i changed it and it gives me this error ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = boolean
LINE 2:             when code::text like '1%' then 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update labor set type_ = left(code::text, 1)::int8
```

Comment: this should work but it gives me an error function left(integer, integer) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: both columns are integer not numeric sorry about that

Comment: ahh that worked beauty. so much simpler than I thought il accept your answer when the time limit lets me